# Angular Request Can't Access API Control due to CORS

Tags: c#, angular, cors, asp.net-web-api2

I have an end-point which simply uploads profile pictures. Eventhough I have enabled CORS, frontend team keeps telling me that they cannot be able to reach that end-point due to below error:

> zone.js:2990 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://gogobioimages.testortami.com/api/Image/PostAccountPicture' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

They are developing on Angular. On the other hand, mobile team (developing on Xamarin) don't have any problem on reaching that end-point. Below is my breakdown of API controller.

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class BaseController : ApiController
{
    //common methods used on every controller written here
}
```

And, here is the end-point which contains image upload method:

```
public class ImageController : BaseController
{
    [IdentityBasicAuthentication]
    [Authorize]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostAccountPicture()
    {
        //some code here
    }
}
```

First, these `[Authorize]` and `[IdentityBasicAuthentication]` headers were placed on the top of the `ImageController`, but I read that this situation could end up mixing request pipeline, so I moved them on the top of action (didn't solve the problem though).

I also have these customHeader lines on my web.config:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true"/>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

And, my handlers are described as below:

```
<handlers>
  <remove name="WebDAV" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <!--<remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />-->
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" path="*" verb="OPTIONS" modules="ProtocolSupportModule" requireAccess="None" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

At the beginning, I don't have `name="OPTIONSVerbHandler"`. After I added it to web.config, mobile requests start to getting 500 Internal Server Error.

Below is my Global.asax, which I have editted as per other suggestions (`Application_BeginRequest` was not included at the beginning):

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new FormMultipartEncodedMediaTypeFormatter());
    }

    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, my `WebApiConfig` class as per below:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*"));

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

I have also asked my front-end mate to share her ajax request with me. Its like that:

```
  $("form").submit(function(evt){evt.preventDefault(); var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]); $.ajax({
url: 'https://<our subdomain name is here>/api/Image/PostAccountPicture',
type: 'POST',
data: formData,
async: false,
cache: false,
contentType: false,
enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
processData: false,
headers: {'Authorization':'Basic ' + localStorage.getItem('currentUser')} ,
success: function (response) {
  alert(response);
}});return false;});
```

I have also enabled CORS in my previous projects, and it was enough to set `[EnableCors("*","*","*")]` on the controller classes and making `config.EnableCors()` on `WebApiConfig.cs` without all the other above shown adjustments like the ones on web.config file.

Now, I don't have any idea what keeps front-end to reach my end-point.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: can you share the angular code

Comment: @EhsanKiani thank you for your interest. I am too far away from Angular and I am glad if you tell me exactly what you need from Angular side. I have already share their ajax request in my question

Comment: I've had the same problem and it solved by removing header from my angular request

Comment: @EhsanKiani but she needs to send me a user token via header area?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on my side when developing with angular and using a local server between my browser and the backend (in order to update the gui on the fly when code change). We solved the issue by just adding the [Allow CORS Plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi)
Chrome (and I suppose other browsers) dislike when the server handling the paages is not the same as the server where api calls are sent.

This of course is no issue in production as the browser is reaching the expected server and not a kind of man in the middle server.

Comment: Sadly this didn't help us. I checked my teammate's chorme and it already has this plugin. I simply turn it on and trigger the request again, but CORS error still exists

Answer (score 0):

Could you try in the angular end to send cross-origin / cross-domain : true
Like the below way

**headers: {
        'Authorization':'Basic ' + localStorage.getItem('currentUser'),
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
     }**

Comment: now the error turns into `The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed.`

Comment: i editted my firend's ajax as per your last update, but we are receiving the same error as per my above comment

Comment: Are you accessing the rest api with ssl /tls protocol with Http request from client end.?

Comment: yes, rest API's URL begins with https and localhost is not

Comment: then it is not a secure layer communication. Try with https://localhost with same headers

Answer (score -2):

**Disclaimer: Only for development purposes.**

> Only during development, I had a use case in my angular app where I had to fetch mock data from an external URL. I tried setting headers   & proxy but eventually found this addon which worked like a charm.
>
> Try [`CORS Everywhere`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cors-everywhere/) addon/extension for firefox.
>
> If using chrome or edge(chromium), checkout chrome webstore.

*Note: **Use at your own risk**. Make sure you understand what kind of permissions you are giving to these addons/extensions.*

**FYI**: *If the link(s) are dead at some point in time, try googling it, duh. ;)*